# Assignment that I ran stops working after first InputDialog, how could I fix it?

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShippingCost
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the length of your package: ");
      double length=input.nextDouble();
 
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the width of your package: ");
      double width=input.nextDouble();
 
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the height of your package: ");
      double height=input.nextDouble();
 
      double dimensions= length * width * height;
      System.out.println("The total dimensions of your package is: " + dimensions);
      
      double charge=0;
      double surcharge;
      double additionalCharge;
      double totalCost;
```

Code compiles just fine, however running it as an application to test out the inputs is where I run into the issue that I have. First input box appears, then won't do anything else after hitting enter. I'm super new the Java and only stuck on this...

Comment: `showInputDialog` is not providing any input to `System.in`. On a more general note, this is one of the many reasons not to mix GUI and console style apps. Choose one or the other and stick with it. In this particular case, note that `showInputDialog` returns a `String`. On a more general note, a `JSpinner` using a `SpinnerNumberModel` is a good way to get numerical input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the return value of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` to get the user's inputs, e.g.

```
double length = Double.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the length of your package: "));
```

and so on.

Comment: We should also discuss the fact that `showInputDialog` can return `null` or a non-numerical value as well, because that's going to otherwise come back to haunt us